# SerialDevice C# Create Custom Start Byte

Tags: c#, serial-communication

So i'm trying to create a C# code to communicate to a serial device that is conected to my PC. But that device requires a Start Byte to communicate with my code. I try sending it after SerialDevice class is created and i get it's OutputStream but the device just don't respond at all.

The DeviceInformation of that device says that it can't pair. I think it's because the DeviceInformation class request a communication with my device and it don't responde because it lacks the Start byte.

Is there a way for me to create a custom conection with my SerialDevice beside this class?

Or is there a way for me to configure the start byte in the declaration of the SerialDevice class?

Answer (score 0):

Start byte is: STX, 0x02.

Explain more what you've done so far if you need more help!

Comment: End byte is ETX 0x03.

Answer (score 0):

The device i'm trying to integrate requires that the start byte is as it follows:

`#define FINGERPRINT_STARTCODE 0xEF01`

This is a C code that is in the docummentation of the device.
As i'm trying to migrate it to C# i'm not being abble to change the start byte and therefore the device doesn't responde to my C# code.

This is me declarating the SerialDevice:

```
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("UART0");

            var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

            UartPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);

            UartPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);   
            UartPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);    
            UartPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            UartPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            UartPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            UartPort.DataBits = 8;

            DataWriterObject = new DataWriter(UartPort.OutputStream);
            DataReaderObject = new DataReader(UartPort.InputStream);
```

And then i try to send data through the DataWriter with my start byte:

```
 private async Task<int> EnviarPacote(Package package)
    {
        int sum;
        DataWriterObject.WriteBytes(package.start);
        DataWriterObject.WriteByte(package.address[0]);
        DataWriterObject.WriteByte(package.address[1]);
        DataWriterObject.WriteByte(package.address[2]);
        DataWriterObject.WriteByte(package.address[3]);
        DataWriterObject.WriteInt16(package.type);
        int tamanho = 12;
        DataWriterObject.WriteInt32(tamanho);
        //DataWriterObject.WriteBytes(package.length);
        sum = tamanho + package.type;
        foreach (var dado in package.data)
        {
            DataWriterObject.WriteByte(dado);

        }
        DataWriterObject.WriteInt32(12);
        await UartPort.OutputStream.WriteAsync(DataWriterObject.DetachBuffer());
        return sum;
    }
```

And it just doesn't work.

I guess i should change something in my SerialDevice declaration so that the class knows how to communicate with my device. But i don't know how.

Comment: `0xEF01` won't fit in a byte, it takes at least two.  So now you have to worry about byte order.

Comment: I noteced that but the only order options that i found was LittleEndian and BigEndian. And as i understood, neither supply my needs. @BenVoigt